# Update total amount of likes with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have created a like button for my page using jquery, html and php. And now I'm trying to read out the total amount of likes.

When I click on the  it goes through my jquery and php and returns the total amount in my console. But I can't see it on the page until I update the page.

PHP and HTML

```
 <?php


$page = new CMS();
$gp = $page->getPage();


foreach ($gp as $sp) {
  //var_dump($sp);

  echo "<div class='pub'>";

  echo "<h4 class='pub-headline'>" . $sp['title'] . "</h4>"; 
  echo "<article class='pub_art'>" . $sp['content'] . "</article>";  
  echo "<p class='pub_created'>" . $sp['created'] . "</p>"; 
  echo "<p class='pub_created_by'>". $sp['writer'] ."</p>";

  echo "<button class='show'>Show</button>"; 
  echo "<button class='noshow'>Hide</button>";

  echo "<div class='vote_widget'>";  
  echo "<div class='voting' onclick='vote(" . $sp['id'] . ", 1)'></div>";

  echo"<div class='total_likes'>" . $sp['likes'] . "</div>";

  echo"</div>";

  echo "</div>";

 }
?>
```

Jquery

```
function vote(id, likes) {


    $.post("classCalling4.php", 
            { id: id, likes: likes }, function(result){

                console.log(result)
                $(".total_likes" + id) .html(result);
                ;
    });
```

OOP PHP

```
    public function updateLikes($id, $likes) {

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $id);
    $likes = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $likes);

    $id = intval($id);
    $likes = intval($likes);


    $sql = "UPDATE pages
    SET likes = likes+1
    WHERE id = $id ";

    $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql) or die("Fel vid SQL query 1"); // Hit kommer jag


    $sql2 = "SELECT * from pages WHERE id = $id ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2) or die ("Fel vid SQL query 2");


    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $tot_likes = $row['likes']; 

    echo $tot_likes;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add the id to class name because you suppose this in your jquery script:

```
$(".total_likes" + id) .html(result);
```

so your html should be:

```
echo"<div class='total_likes".$sp['id']."'>" . $sp['likes'] . "</div>";
```

and if you use this class to give style you can replace the class with id:

```
echo"<div class='total_likes' class='total_likes".$sp['id']."'>".$sp['likes']."</div>";
```

and your javascript should be:

```
$("#total_likes" + id) .html(result);
```

Comment: Indeed! or remove the "+ id" from the jquery if you just want the class to be total_likes

Comment: @MatthewLymer I think your solution invalid, because he has alot of div total, it inside foreach

Comment: Thanks dude! Worked awsome

Comment: @mackeemackee you are welcome, you can accept anser if solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Since, the `total_likes` is in `foreach` loop so you should concate `id` with the class name to make it unique. 
So, instead of

```
  echo"<div class='total_likes'>" . $sp['likes'] . "</div>";
```

do this

```
 echo"<div class='total_likes'".$sp['id'].">" . $sp['likes'] . "</div>";
```